# Evaluation of logical condition in ternary operator

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

I do not know whether parens are required **before** the ternary operator.

Example:

```
int a,b,d,e,f; // Some numbers
int l = ( a > b || d < e ) ? a : d;
```

is surely fine, if `a>b` or `d<e` then `l = a` else `l = d`.
I am not sure if instead

```
int l =  a > b || d < e ? a : d;
```

is equally valid, and what about longer statements?

```
int l = ( a > b || d ) && e > f ? a : d;
```

I guess that my question is: the ternary operator always treat whatever comes before him as a logical expression and evaluates it, and therefore there is no need for parens before it?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Extra parens take no compute time, but can save tons of maintenance time

Comment: (((Parsing (redundant parentheses)) (when (you read))) (can be confusing)).

Comment: easier to parse extra than debug missing.  but yes, there are limits.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is correct.

And the second statement is equally valid to the first one.

Your second example reads as follows:
`(...)` have highest precedence and `>` and `<` have higher precedence than `&&` which has higher precedence than `||` which has higher precedence than `?:`.
So

- if the result of `a > b || d` (d is converted to 1 if different than 0) is `true`
  **and**
- if the result of `e > f` is `true`
  **then**
- `l=a`
- otherwise `l=b`.

Comment: So "yes" but please please please use parens anyway. The fact that this question had to be asked shows that the precedence isn't inherently clear and should be enforced with parens.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, you might want to add the table of precedence from the commenter to my question to make your answer complete.

@LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, you are probably right. I had a vague notion, but as coding amateur without formal training I didn't know where to look for it, thanks to this question now I know. Hope it helps other amateur like me.